# Difference between Committed_AS and sum of the VSZ column in ps

Tags: linux, memory-management

I'm running the following two commands on my system and coming up with different numbers:

```
[root@rhel6 ~] grep Committed_AS /proc/meminfo
Committed_AS:      82964 kB

[root@rhel6 ~]# ps aux | awk '{vsz+=$5}END{print vsz}'
1580824
```

My understanding is that Committed_AS is the amount of virtual memory currently allocated on the system. In my second command I'm summing the VSZ column (allocated virtual memory reported in kB) from the output of 'ps aux'.

Why aren't these numbers the same? They're VERY different, so I'm obviously not understanding something along the way.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

One reason those numbers are so different is that the process can reserve virtual address ranges as inaccessible, simply to prevent future calls such as mmap() from using them accidentally.   Such inaccessible ranges are included in VSS, but not in Committed_AS.

Here are two examples of when such inaccessible ranges are used:

1) If you are using libc malloc in a multi-threaded process, it typically creates multiple "arenas" as a way to help reduce lock contention between threads doing malloc at the same time.  For every arena other than the first one (called the main arena) the memory is reserved in fixed size heaps.  In the 64-bit case those heaps are 64 megabytes each but when a heap is initially created, only the beginning is given RW access.  The tail of the heap is made inaccessible and as the heap grows the process gradually expands the part that is readable and writable and shrinks the part that is inaccessible.

2) When shared libraries are loaded, some of the sections have alignment constraints as large as 2MB in a recent 64-bit Linux process.  Typically this leaves one inaccessible region in the middle of the address range used by each shared library, and such regions are generally either 2MB or 2MB-4K in size.